# Parsing RSS 2.0 Feeds in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to use these classes http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/22/parsing-rss-20-feeds-in-actionscript-3/ with flash professional. The issue I'm running into is some of the parsing classes use mx classes which I can't seem to use in flash Professional. Anyone able to get these classes to work without mx.

Comment: Did you download and reference as3syndicationlib and corelib swc libraries?

Comment: Yep did that none of them have mx files. There was no swc just the AS files.

Comment: Ok I've looked everywhere in the trunk for svn and there is no swc file anywhere. Jason do you know where to download the swc file.

Comment: [xmlsyndication](http://as3syndicationlib.googlecode.com/files/xmlsyndication-.85.zip) SWC is in the ZIP bin/ folder, and I've built [as3corelib](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/builds/as3corelib.swc) for you.

Comment: Thank you for the swc that did the trick. For some reason the only one that is giving trouble still is XMLUtil.isValidXML. I get an error when I call this. "Call to a possibly undefined method isValidXML through a reference with static type Class."

Comment: Answer with FLA example in just a minute...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13024/discussion-between-jason-sturges-and-chapsterj)

Comment: Hi Jason sorry I had to go to bed I was exhausted. Are you around today. I found this link that talks about whats causing the issue. Apparently there is a similar file in CS5 already that is in conflict with the XMLUtil fil in the swc. http://forum.oxylusflash.com/clean-as3-news-ticker-01-rss/7600-files-size-incorrect.html

Answer (score 1):

This example has two SWC library dependencies.

[xmlsyndication](http://as3syndicationlib.googlecode.com/files/xmlsyndication-.85.zip) SWC is built and available from the ZIP file's bin/ folder.

[as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) is available from GitHub but not built; however, I've [compiled a build for you](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/builds/as3corelib.swc).  Note that it includes AIR classes which will throw build errors if you're targeting Flash Player.  If you are building for Flash Player and not AIR, delete the air folder from src/com/adobe/air.

Link these SWCs to your Flash Project.

[image: actionscript settings]

Paste Mike Chambers example [RSSExampleClass](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/22/parsing-rss-20-feeds-in-actionscript-3/) class in the actions of a keyframe and add the `outputField` text field and a button to call `onLoadPress`.

[image: flash]

Run and you'll see:

[image: swf]

Flash Professional CS5 FLA of this example available at:
http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/rss-reader/rss-reader.zip

My example project includes:

- bin/

  - RSS.swf
- libs/

  - as3corelib.swc
  - xmlsyndication.swc
- src/

  - RSS.fla

Comment: Thanks so much Jason. When I publish from your fla I get this error Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 59 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method isValidXML through a reference with static type Class.  I get the same error on my work too.

Comment: Go to ActionScript settings and browse to make sure both SWCs paths are correct.  I referenced them relative.